# change image url during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Image id="voteaccepeted" 
     ImageUrl="~/UserControls/Vote/Images/before_accept.png" 
     runat="server" class="vote-accept" />
```

i want to change image url during run time

```
if( bestanswer == true)
{
// change url..
}
```

how i do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine this would work (after fixing up the names elsewhere):

```
if (bestAnswer)
{
    voteAccepted.ImageUrl = "some other url";
}
```

That's the most obvious approach, anyway - so if that *doesn't* work, please give us more information, such as where in the page lifecycle you're trying to do this, what happened when you tried, and what other diagnostics you've performed.

(By the way, you've got `runat="server"` twice in your HTML...)

Comment: jon sir can u see " ajax call error for list view data item." this question i have asked but so far i didn't get answer.

Comment: @Nishant: I know very little JavaScript, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (bestanswer)
{
    voteaccepeted.ImageUrl = "~/newurlpath.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if using javascript, you can try

```
document.getElementById('voteaccepeted').src = 'http://...';  // or relative path name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
voteAccepted.ImageUrl = "some other url";
```

If its in updatePanel also update it if its property UpdateMode="Conditional"

```
UpdatePanel.Update();
```